# Sci-Fi series from the '80s, maybe older

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm looking for what I'm only fairly confident was a TV series (not a movie). I watched this most likely in the early '90s on private free-tv outside prime time. I also remember it "being different" from the sci-fi series I knew back then, which makes me believe that it is not a U.S. production. Perhaps from Canada? ("Outer Limits" is also "different.")

I remember a male protagonist, a female companion, at least one other guy. They were being chased by some zombie-like monsters - likely aliens. They were, as far as I can remember, humanoid in shape.

The group was cornered by the monster and the protagonist started singing a choral-like song to chase them away - with at least temporary success. He explained that the monsters can be driven away by faith and that it was not important what you believed, as long as it was something that you truly believed in.

Later, I guess the group got somehow separated, that other guy was being attacked and he took a book - likely a Bible - held it defensively in front of him with both hands and started to sing, but it didn't work, because there was no faith behind it.

Since he was facing pretty certain death, he desperately tried to come up with something he truly believed in. The last thing was something like "I believe in the Good(ness)!!!" (German: "Ich glaube an das Gute!!!") which he kept repeating until he was eventually killed...

A couple more things that might be helpful: The protagonist - don't remember his name - was definitely an alien though perfectly human looking. In fact, I think, most humans weren't aware of him being an alien. I think he was the only alien of his species, though there were others around. Some classic sci-fi elements, such as space ships, space battles, laser guns and the like were missing. I think time travel may have been mentioned.

Goodness, this is becoming more interesting than I thought...

Comment: You might want to provide a more descriptive question title, that includes some significant details about the show in order to help people archive and find the question better.

Comment: Did the protagonist try to use an old Chess problem to stymie the bad guy? A trick question involving pawns switching sides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the original link-only answer was deleted, I'll place my answer here. :)

The BBC series Doctor Who, near the end of its original 26 year run, had an episode titled [The Curse of Fenric](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0562902/). It was actually four episodes in the original half-hour format they used as the time. This link is to Part One.

I recognize all of the details mentioned in the question from this episode. Here's a synopsis from Wikipedia:

> The Doctor and Ace arrive at a British naval installation near
>   Maiden's Point on the Northumbrian coast during World War II.
>   Befriending the base personnel, they learn that the base, run by
>   Commander Millington, is being used as a listening post to intercept
>   and translate German coded messages using the Ultima supercomputer and
>   to stockpile a supply of a lethal nerve gas. Meanwhile,
>   wheelchair-user Dr. Judson has also been using Ultima to help decipher
>   Viking runes found in catacombs beneath the base, warning of a being
>   called Fenric, which has attracted Millington's attention, he
>   believing that he can gain Fenric's power. Outside the base, the
>   Doctor and Ace discover a covert squad of Soviet commandos, led by
>   Captain Sorin, who are seeking to capture Ultima; the Doctor warns
>   them to lie low, while Ace and Sorin become smitten with each other.
>
> The Doctor and Ace find a glowing oriental vase, a treasure captured
>   by the Vikings and left in the catacombs, but it is taken by
>   Millington when they return to the base. As Millington and Judson
>   prepare to use Ultima to decipher the writings on the vase,
>   vampire-like Haemovores begin to emerge from the sea, attack and
>   convert the English and Soviet troops and other residents into more
>   Haemovores. When Judson runs Ultima with the vase, energy strikes him
>   and he becomes infused with Fenric. Fenric begins to give orders to
>   the Ancient One, an old Haemovore in control of the other monsters, to
>   continue to assault anyone in their path. Ace is able to warn one of
>   the WRNS, Kathleen, in time for her to escape with her newborn child,
>   Audrey.
>
> The Doctor reveals he has faced Fenric, an ancient evil since the dawn
>   of time, besting him by challenging him at a chess problem. Arranging
>   another chess problem in the same room where the nerve gas has been
>   stockpiled, the Doctor is able to delay Fenric, while he runs off to
>   seek a more permanent solution. Sorin, the last remaining member of
>   his squad, enters the room and prepares to shoot Fenric, but Fenric
>   reveals that Sorin is one of his "wolves", having descended from the
>   Vikings that carried the cursed vase to the English shores and takes
>   over his body. When Ace returns to the room, she unwittingly helps
>   Fenric, in Sorin's body, to solve the chess problem. The Doctor
>   arrives too late, as Fenric can no longer be stopped. Fenric orders
>   the Ancient One to attack the Doctor but a psychic barrier created by
>   Ace's trust in the Doctor prevents the Ancient One from acting. The
>   Doctor is forced to reveal to Ace that she too is one of Fenric's
>   pawns, as it was he that created the time storm that transported her
>   to the alien world where she met the Doctor the first time.[2]
>   Furthermore, by saving Kathleen and Audrey, she has assured that the
>   cycle remain unbroken, as Audrey will grow up to become Ace's mother
>   whom she despises. Ace's faith is shattered, causing the psychic
>   barrier to drop but, instead of attacking the Doctor, the Ancient One
>   grabs Fenric, pulls him into a sealed chamber and releases a lethal
>   dose of the gas. The chamber explodes, killing them both. As the
>   Doctor and Ace recover along the shore, Ace takes a moment to
>   contemplate why she hates her mother and to celebrate overcoming her
>   irrational fear of the water, before she and the Doctor return to the
>   Tardis.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like the 1979 TV series Salem's Lot. Based on the Stephen King book of the same name, it deals with an invasion of vampires in a small rural town. Here's a trailer:

Comment: Doesn't ring a bell. I'm sure it's not Steven King and it's sci-fi, so no vampires. I'll add some more details in the original posting, that came to my mind over time...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the TV show you are looking for is The war of the worlds.